# Custom field checkbox option seems non-searchable because of + character in value. How to access my data?

Tags: custom-fields

I created a custom field months ago with checkbox options for age categories, including an option with the value '65 and +'. I can search for the other values of the same field without any problem (ex. search for 30 to 54 years) through an advanced search, but when I search for '65 et +' it never finds any results. I suppose because of the + character?

I don't seem to be able to use a wildcard in the advanced search, since it seems to only allow me to search for one or another of the checkbox options. I tried the search builder as well, but searching for results in the field like '65' or like '65%' also gives no results.

This is quite a problem at the moment, because we collected more than a year worth of data on people who use our services, and we need to produce reports for our funders including their age.

Any idea of how I can get at this data? Will I need to modify the custom field checkbox value? In the past I've managed to do some basic operations through APIv3 or APIv4 and I know some SQL, so maybe there is some way I can get a copy of the already complex advanced search query and just modify the part with that designates the '65 and +' checkbox option?

Thanks very much for any help!